# Converting MP4 from input folder, moving them to new output, resizing with FFMPEG

Tags: bash, input, ffmpeg, resize

I would like to know how to do the following :

There are 2 folders on my desktop. One is called input, the other output.

- 1 : Input folder contains a number of MP4 video files.
- 2 : I execute a .SH script (OSX) and all MP4 video files in the
  folder will be resized to 2 other sizes for HLS.
- 3 : The original video in the folder, the highest version, will be
  also moved to the output folder after the other 2 versions were
  rescaled and created by FFMPEG in the output folder.

After this, we will use the Apple segmentation tool to segment all 3 versions, and automatically deleting the 3 MP4 video's left in the output folder.

I am not experienced with programming, hence I can use some help on this.

As far as I came with some code :

```
#!/bin/bash
Cd ~/username/Desktop/input
for name in *.mp4; do
  ffmpeg -i "$name" -vf scale=854:480 "../output/${name%.*}_middle.mp4" 
  ffmpeg -i "$name" -vf scale=426:240 "../output/${name%.*}_low.mp4" 
  mv "$name" "../output/${name%.*}_high.mp4"
```

Thanks heaps in advance,

John

Comment: this looks a lot like it's not about batch. Are you sure you aren't using bash, instead of the windows batch-files?

Comment: You are right. I added the correct tag. Thank you.